# Return "YES"/"NO" based on date comparison in sql

Tags: sql

I want to write a sql query for the following excel-query. What should be the appropriate query?

```
IF

(
    (project. PA_SUBMIT_DATE )-(project. PA_AGREED_SUBMIT_DATE) 
    >=0;
    "YES";
    "NO"
)
```

i.e Date difference should be greater than or equal to zero. If so return yes else no.Please help me here.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It would look something like this:

```
(case when project.PA_SUBMIT_DATE >= project.PA_AGREED_SUBMIT_DATE
      then 'YES' else 'NO'
 end)
```

Note:  You can use `>=` for dates in both Excel and SQL and (I think) it makes the code easier to understand.  The rest is just the standard SQL for a condition in a `select`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate your time

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you want to return a "YES" if the `PA_SUBMIT_DATE` is greater than or equal to the `PA_AGREED_SUBMIT_DATE`:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN PA_SUBMIT_DATE >= PA_AGREED_SUBMIT_DATE 
          THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' 
       END AS [ColumnName]
FROM PROJECT
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Appreciate your time